# Spinnaker front50 is unable to access Oracle Object Storage

Tags: oracle, kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I have setup spinnaker using halyard, and the official oracle oci documentation:
https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/post/spinnaker-for-application-deployment-on-oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Everything goes fine and it deploys successfully, but front50 and echo containers, which are inter-related, go into crashloopbackoff because it cannot access the object storage bucket.

Error message:

```
POST https://objectstorage.my-region.oraclecloud.com/n/my-tenancy/b/ returned a response status of 400 Bad Request
```

I have created Oracle provider according to this:
https://spinnaker.io/docs/setup/install/providers/oracle/

and object storage according to this:
https://spinnaker.io/docs/setup/install/storage/oracle/

Both use a real IAM user, and his credentials.

In the command reference for oracle provider I see these parameters, which are not given in spinnaker site examples. I dont know if these are required to be given? The IAM user used for provider already has access to the bucket given in storage.

```
--read-permissions

--required-group-membership

--write-permissions
```

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve the issue with Oracle support. The issue was that the namespace parameter for the storage provider definition was not equal to our tenancy. (Unlike in the oracle provider definition where namespace = tenancy)